# Load testing programs recommendations

Tags: load

I am looking for a program to test loading.

I understand that Jmeter and loadrunner both do this (though loadrunner is paid while jmeter is not)

What I need to test is minimum 1000 users at the same time. all they need to be able to do is run a very short flash movie clip and make sure that it doesn't crash, and calls the correct files.

Are there better programs? Preferably free... But even if not - anyone know what are the typical costs and names of other similar programs? (possibly even online/ cloud solutions?)

Thanks everybody

Answer (score 2):

The Grinder is another possibility:

http://grinder.sourceforge.net/

It's free, a mature product and fairly flexible.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209930/jmeter-versus-the-grinder) has some more information you might find relevant.

Answer (score 1):

If you like to run more than 1000 concurrent users, you need distributed test framework. As far as I know, loadrunner may require many agents to meet your requirements becaz it handles few virtual user per an agent.

As davek said, The Grinder might be the good choice. Please refer the how to test the stream in the following link.

http://www.cubrid.org/wiki_ngrinder/entry/how-to-handle-the-big-response

Answer (score 1):

Grinder and Jmeter both reproduce HTTP traffic on the network. In your question you mentioned movie clips which are client side executions. If you have trouble reproducing the HTTP traffic from a RIA (Ajax or other), you might want to look at the Headless Browser approach under which a tool like Selenium executes against multiple Headless Browsers in a VM. This will in turn generate the required HTTP traffic for you.

Answer (score 1):

I use `siege` which is an http load testing and benchmarking utility.

Output sample https://gist.github.com/mikaelz/5687636

I have it from https://vimeo.com/13768954

Answer (score 1):

The TCPCopy could also do this:

https://github.com/wangbin579/tcpcopy

It's a mature open source project popular in China.

This following link may help you know how to use it.
http://globaldev.co.uk/2013/01/migrating-memcached/